# iOS continuous build server from svn

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration

I need some tips regarding continuous integration for iOS application. My previous build system was with Jenkins.

Jenkins in a windows machine ssh to my Mac, build it and then upload to an internal server for testers.

http://i-phone-dev.blogspot.no/2013/07/jenkin-build-xcode-project-in-mac-slave.html

But I would like to update my build server and want to have a dedicated build server for continuous integration. My office have total windows system running with SVN server and other things.

First I will buy a machine, mac mini or mac pro.

I need suggestion on

- Advantage of using Mac Mini Server and Mac Pro

  - I guess now there is no Mac Mini Server now. I see only Mac Mini in Apple website. Probably with Mac Mini I have to buy Mac OS X Server.
- Do I really need OS X server. Or I can use OS X with Jenkins?

But it seems to me like, if I want to use XCode continuous integration then I need OS X Server.

Comment: You need OSX server, that is free now:)

Comment: Sorry now its not free. But previously they have given free version for mavericks. That was for the promotion. Now you have to pay. http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/10/24/apple-offers-developers-free-copies-of-os-x-server-for-mavericks-in-bid-to-keep-apps-fresh

Comment: FYI. Still free if you are a developer.

Comment: stil free, how can I get it?